# Let a user view all info of sys.databaseprincipals

Tags: sql-server

I have a database and I want let to some role the permission to query all info from the sys.databaseprincipals and see other user names. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the call in a stored proc or table valued function and use [EXECUTE AS OWNER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181362(SQL.90).aspx) (assuming dbo.nameofcodeobject).

Otherwise, you have to switch off [MetaData Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187113(SQL.90).aspx) protection for the entire server

You can't use EXECUTE AS for views which would be useful here...

Edit, based on comment.

From [sys.database_principals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187328.aspx):

> In SQL Server 2005 and later versions,
>   the visibility of the metadata in
>   catalog views is limited to securables
>   that a user either owns or on which
>   the user has been granted some
>   permission. For more information, see
>   Metadata Visibility Configuration.

- dbo owns everything so sees everything
- Permissions can not be granted because there is no "GRANT VIEW SECURITY"

Comment: The problem is that I need to access to the sys.database_principals as the dbo sees it through a view.

Comment: dbo can see all data anyway... for other users/roles you'll need to wrap it.

Comment: If I give SELECT permission to the role/user in the view that calls sys.database_principals only shows the users seen by this user.

Comment: I'm not saying change permissions. I'm saying wrap the sys call.

Answer (score 0):

Maybee its just me and my servers setup but I am able to query the sys.database_principals so long as I have the connect permission. I am also able to see the user name.

You can grant Connect by doing:

GRANT CONNECT TO [USER]

Comment: Are you connecting as db_owner?

Comment: You'll only see the users (eg NT groups) that you are associated with. The same applies to sys.server_principals. db_owner and other roles have extended rights

Comment: Nope I am connecting as a SQL User who only has the connect permission. Hmm let me add another user and see if I see him

Comment: Ok I see now. I can see all the roles and dbo guest etc...but not the other user.

Comment: I see far more in dev than on prod because I have far less rights on prod

Comment: Yep well I was logging in with my least privllaged acount, which only has connect. Kind of odd...also when you look at sp_helptext for the view and try and run it it doesnt work complains about functions and then the tables themselves are invalid. I have a lot of catching up on SQL Internals...